Does there exist a deformation complex governing deformations of schemes?
Given a $k$-scheme $X$, then we have a deformation functor
$$Def_X: Art_k \longrightarrow Set : R \longmapsto \frac{\{ R\text{-deformations of } A\}}{\text{equivalences}} $$
as defined for example in Deformations of Algebraic Schemes by E. Sernesi. For good measure: a $R$-deformation of $X$ is given by a flat $R$-scheme $Y$ and a $k$-isomorphism $X \cong Y \times_R k$.
It is well-known that the first order deformations are parametrized by the sheaf cohomology $H^1(X,T_X)$ where $T_X$ is the tangent sheaf of $X$ if $X$ is nonsingular (Prop. 1.2.9 of Sernesi's book). Moreover, obstructions lie inside $H^2(X,T_X)$.
My question is the following: does there exists a dg Lie algebra $L$ governing the above deformation theory/functor for schemes (whose homology should capture $H^1(X,T_X)$)? By this I mean, do $R$-deformations of $X$ correspond to the Maurer-Cartan elements of some dg Lie algebra $L \otimes \mathfrak m_R$?
This question is inspired by the fact that the Harrison complex governs the deformations of commutative algebras and thus affine schemes. I often hear about Kodaira-Spencer theory when talking about deformation theory of schemes, but did they provide a dg Lie structure as well?

This is likely too restrictive (and too non-algebraic) for you, but if $k=\mathbb C$, you can take the Dolbeault resolution of $T_X$, i.e. $(0,\bullet)$-forms with values in vectors. It's a dg Lie algebra and gives you what you want.

@user8268 I assumed the answer would be something non-algebraic :) A result for $k=\mathbb{C}$ is already great. What would be a good source for this result?
